# What's the difference between gitpython's diff and git log's diff?

Tags: git, github, gitpython

I don't understand the difference between the output of `git log -p` and that of `gitpython` in terms of diffs.

For example, for some merge commit `f534e1...`, `git log -p` gives:

```
commit f534e1...
Merge: ....
Author: ....
Date:   ...

Merge pull request ... from ...
```

with **no diff**, which I assume to be correct (the diff comes with the next log entry - one of the parents of `f534e1...`).

I would like to achieve the same effect with `gitpython`. I'm trying:

```
repo = Repo("...")
for c in repo.iter_commits():
  print c.hexsha
  print c.summary
  print c.diff()
```

I get:

```
f534e1...
Merge pull request ... from ...
[<git.diff.Diff object at 0x102cd3490>]
```

with **some diff**.

What diff is this? Why do I get it here? How can I mimic the behavior of `git log -p`?

Comment: What are the actual properties of the `git.diff.Diff` object?

Comment: http://gitpython.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference.html#git.diff.Diff

Comment: Huh, I'd read the docs :) I asked what are the _values_ of those properties? Have you compared the resulted diff (if it actually contains any significant difference, not just an object of git.diff.Diff class), with `git diff ...` with _each_ of the merge parents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://gitpython.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference.html#git.diff.Diffable.diff), `c.diff()` will compare the commit against the index, i.e. staged changes.

It appears that `git log -p` will produce a special-format diff against all of the given commit's parents. Something roughly comparable can be achieved with the following code (based on your example).

```
repo = Repo("...")
for c in repo.iter_commits():
  print c.hexsha
  print c.summary
  for p in c.parents:
    handle_diff(c.diff(p))
```

The latter would yield a [Diff](http://gitpython.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference.html#git.diff.Diff) object with all relevant information.

If what you really want is the exact format produced by `git log -p`, you may also call `repo.git.log(p=True)` and parse the output yourself.